# Send Post Json with ajax and Play Framework 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a problem regarding sending a json data to Play Controller.

**seach.scala.html**

```
$.ajax({
            type :  "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'filter': "John Portella"
            },
            url  :  "@routes.Search.findPag()",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
```

**Controller :** `POST       /find/findPag      Search.findPag()`

```
public static Result findPag(){    
   JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
   return ok();
}
```

Debugging I get json = null . Which you think may be the problem?.
Thank.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to [stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) the data. As it is right now I think that `.toString()` will be called on the data object and that is not something that can be correctly parsed as JSON on the server side.

```js
var d = { 'filter': "John Portella" };
$.ajax({
    type :  "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(d),
    url  :  "@routes.Search.findPag()",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to "contentType" the data.

```
 var d = { 'filter': "John Portella" };
 $.ajax({
    type :  "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(d),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url  :  "@routes.Search.findPag()",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
 });
```